# In Dwarf Fortresss, how do you verify that the civilization you're embarking from isn't too small to provide migrants?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

The wiki states: "There is just ONE BIG RULE: when your home civilization is too small, you will recognize after the second winter that you won't get any more immigrants, which can be extremely fun. To avoid this situation, select a home civilization with at least two dwarven sites on the map."

How do you determine that a civilization has at least two sites?

Answer (score 1):

Before you embark, take note of your civilization's name.  Look them up in Legends mode.  It's easiest if you have Legends Viewer installed but it can be done in the base game as well.  You should be able to see a list of all the sites that civilization controls.

Just a note, you don't necessarily need more than one other site, so long as that site is large and safe.

Answer (score -1):

While looking up a civilisation in legends mode is probably the most reliable way, you can also get an indication of a civilisation's size from the world map. When you select a civilisation its sides are highlighted on the map. That way you can distinguish them from sides of other civilisations and get a rough estimate of its size.

It is probably worth noting that a civilizations size can decrease during the game, so you’re not completely safe.

I never bothered checking and never had migration run out (as far as I can remember). So I would assume it is not something you need to be terribly worried about.

Comment: I think this question pertains specifically to the size at which a civilization starts providing migrants